# Clean URL of PHP file with a JSON response

Tags: php, api

I'm a bit new to all of this and have looked up various solutions but I seem to be constantly implementing it wrong.

I have a PHP file that returns JSON that I want to use to build an API.

Here is my example URL:

```
https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/cardinfo.php?name=Kuriboh
```

This currently returns a JSON output for users to use.

Is it possible, through .htaccess or another method to convert the URL so this can be used:

```
https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/cardinfo/name/Kuriboh
```

Or maybe something along those lines.

I feel like I'm not quite understanding what I am doing. I have a PHP file that returns information as requested. Is that still considered an API even though I don't have the proper syntax for the URL in place?

Comment: I would recommend looking in to routes. There are many good libraries out there. Regarding "Is that still considered an API", yes. There isn't a particular URL format for API's in general. Using `htaccess` is not recommended since it's vendor specific. If you move your app to some other web server (like nginx), you need to set up all the rewrite rules there as well. Using a router moves the responsibility of routing the requests correctly to your app instead (which makes muck more sense).

Comment: Yes, it's still an API.  What you're looking for are server rewrite rules depending on your server.  If it's Apache, .htaccess is a good place to start looking.

Comment: I would suggest just getting an already existing framework that does this for you with routes, some good really minimal ones are Slim Framework, Fat-Free-Framework etc